# How to store json string in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, json

Have small problem with storing json string in mysql table.
String for example:

```
'{"variable":"content here with \" addsleshes "}'
```

created with json_encode.
Store this string in DB with simple mysqli_query function.

```
mysqli_query('insert into ... values \'{"variable":"content here with \" addsleshes "}\' ');
```

After this :

```
  mysqli_query('select *..');
 mysqli_fetch_array($res);
```

When I get this field from Mysql and try to use php json_decode it will return NULL because I no longer have the slash before the " . Cannot use addslashes function as it will add slashes also like \"variable\".
Not sure how to solve this problem?

Comment: You will have to show how you store this string,a nd how you retrieve it. A properly done system will NOT be stripping those slashes from the text.

Comment: updated the question. im using now for testing simply mysqli_query funciton in case my DB class is changing something, but still the same problem

Comment: well, yeah, you haven't escaped that string properly. If you had, the backslash that json_encode added would've gotten into the database. In other words, you're suffering from an [sql injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerability, and this string "corruption" is a symptom of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you try reverse of it.

Use `mysqli_escape_string` before actually passing *JSON* to `mysqli_query`

```
$json = '["Json","Just a Sample Data","Data 2"]'
mysqli_query('insert into ... values'.mysqli_escape_string($json));
```

Now, When you retrieve data from database

```
mysqli_query('select *..');
mysqli_fetch_array($res);
```

Use `stripslashes($str)` to remove slashes from JSON.

It'll work the same way you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
'{"variable":"content here with \\" addsleshes "}'
```

Comment: Yes, was thinking about this but im using json_encode to create a json string from php array. so i would have to do addslashes to every array cell before using json_enocde?

Comment: no. json_encode() will do all the escaping for you. You need to figure out what/where is stripping the slash from the text.